# Is it possible to instruct Serilog to dump each log entry to a separate json file?

Tags: c#, serilog

I am developing a service, which has to dump each log entry as a separate json file. Then, all these dumped log files will be imported to ElasticSearch. I am aware of ElasticSearch sink, but the idea is not to lose logs when ElasticSearch is unavailable.

One workaround is:

1. To use TextWriter sink with StringWriter;
2. Dump StringWriter contents to json file;
3. And clear underlying StringBuilder after each call.

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom `ILogEventSink` added with `WriteTo.Sink(...)` is needed for this. The `JsonFormatter` class shipped with Serilog makes this fairly quick to implement I think.

Comment: Great! I will give it a try later today.